# Bash programming - variable only to be returned when script called from another script

Tags: bash

I start `main_bla_bla.sh` and pass variables to another bash script `do_something.sh`. `do_something.sh` is intended to be used on its own too and finally fires an `echo` for a variable (call it `sum_var`) at the end of a long calculation.

However when invoked from `main_bla_bla.sh` - how to return `sum_var`, but also insuring that it does not cause any issues when having `do_something.sh` started on its own?

Sorry for asking in case; I am a newbie in bash scripting...

Tia

Comment: It is better to post also the code you are working on (with a sample of the desired output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just keep `echo`:

```
echo "$sum_var"
```

And in calling program grab it by:

```
my_sum_var=$(./do_something.sh)
```

This doesn't have any implication on the fact the `do_something.sh` can also be called independently from command line.